# 'FBLoginButton' conform to 'View'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I try to create a Facebook button but when I call it in the VStack it says: `'Referencing initializer 'init(alignment:spacing:content:)' on 'VStack' requires that 'FBLoginButton' conform to 'View''`, So why isn't it working because FBLoginButton is a button after all.
here's the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            FBLoginButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100), permissions: ["email"])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the Implementation of FBLoginButton?

Comment: If you use the FBLoginButton from facebook, then you need to wrapp it in a UIViewRepresentable so that you can use it in SwiftUI: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewrepresentable

Answer (score 1):

First of all needs to create class which implements UIViewRepresentable protocol.

```
import FBSDKLoginKit
import SwiftUI
struct FacebookLoginButton: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = FBLoginButton
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIViewType {
        FBLoginButton()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: FBLoginButton, context: Context) { }
}
```

After all this FacebookLoginButton can be used in SwiftUI like this:

```
var body: some View {
    FacebookLoginButton()
}
```

Comment: This works as expected

Answer (score 0):

Facebook SDK still uses UIKit, and FBLoginButton is UIView from UIKit, not View" from SwiftUI.

You need to use loginmanger which does most of the work and embed it inside swiftui Button.

Check link below which will be helpful.
https://gist.github.com/zydeico/8bb9c772e944d1490335e1615aaf4960